# show color coded legend beside scatter plot

Tags: r

Looking at this code:

```
pairs(Iris[1:3], main = "Anderson's Iris Data -- 3 species",
pch = c(21),  cex = 2,bg = c("red","green3","blue")[unclass(iris$Species)])
```

is it possible to show the groups/classes Species as legend color coded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a non-overlapping legend to associate colors with categories in pairs()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201325/how-to-add-a-non-overlapping-legend-to-associate-colors-with-categories-in-pairs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pairs(iris[1:3], main = "Anderson's Iris Data -- 3 species",
      pch = c(21),  cex = 2, bg = c("red","green3","blue")[unclass(iris$Species)], oma=c(4,4,6,10))
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend(0.55, 1, as.vector(unique(iris$Species)),  fill=c("red", "green3", "blue"))
```

From ?pairs:
Graphical parameters can be given as arguments to plot such as main. par("oma") will be set appropriately unless specified. Hence any attempts to specify par before pairs will result in override.

Additionally it is very complicated to control the legend position in `pairs`.

[image]

I recommend using library(GGally)

```
library(GGally)
ggpairs(iris, aes(color = Species), columns = 1:4)
```

[image]