# Adding legend to a pairs() plot

Tags: r, plot, legend, pca

I'm analyzing 4 comparisons of samples from 4 different diets (chimp, fast food, cafe("human"), pellet). When trying to do a pca analysis and plot it using the function pairs(), it gives me this error:plot.new has not been called yet.
The plot has the 4 categories but I don't know which one is which, therefore i'm trying to add a legend but it won't work. Can anyone help with this please?

```
pca=prcomp(t(logdata[,1:24]))
plot(pca)
summary(pca)
#biplot(pca)
pca3d=data.frame(pca$x[,1:3])
head(pca3d)
colnames(pca3d)=c("PC1","PC2","PC3")
x = c(rep("Chimp", 6), rep ("Fast", 6), rep ("Human", 6), rep ("Pellet", 6))
pairs(pca3d,col=c(as.numeric(factor(x))),
      pch=c(as.numeric(factor(x))))
legend("topright", legend=c("Chimp","Fast","Human","Pellet"), 
     col=c("blue","red","green","yellow"),lty=1:2, cex=0.8,
       box.lty=0)
```

*logdata is a matrix that has all the data for the diets.

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390628/show-color-coded-legend-beside-scatter-plot. If not, could you please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @adelriosantiago I tried, still get the same error

Comment: @adelriosantiago so I used ggplots and its working fine now, thank you!